# Encapsulacion en ES6, posible solución

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Podría ser esta la solución a como encapsular metodos usando la sintaxis ES6?? He pasado algunos días investigando como hacerlo y creo que he dado con la solución. Retornando un objeto nuevo desde el constructor con sólo los métodos públicos, tal que así:

```
export default class Foo {

    constructor() {

        /*creates a new freezed object*/
        /*(extends from Object)*/
        return Object.freeze(Object.create({

            /*return a copy of method pointing to this*/
            baz: this.baz.bind(this)
        }));
    }

    baz() { return "This is public!"; }

    _bar() { return "This is private!"; }
}

const foo = new Foo();

console.log(foo.baz()); /*Prints This is public!*/
console.log(foo._bar()); /* Prints Undefined */
```

La clase solo retorna los metodos públicos, creando un nuevo objeto con Object.create() (no hereda el prototipo de la clase, únicamente el de Object), con Object.bind(this) hacemos que apunte a cada una de las instancias, y por último devolvemos una copia congelada del objeto con Object.freeze(foo).

Si intentamos acceder a un método privado nos retorna Undefined porque la propiedad no existe en el prototipo del objeto. En cuanto al tema de la herencia, existe la posibilidad de usar Object.assign(obj) para asignar el prototipo al de la super clase:

```
export default class Foo {

    constructor() {
        /*Call SuperClass constructor*/
        SuperClass.call(this);

        /*creates a new freezed object*/
        /*(extends from SuperClass)*/
        const copy = Object.freeze(Object.create({

            /*return a copy of method pointing to this*/
            baz: this.baz.bind(this)
        }));

        /*Assigning prototype super class to copy*/
        Object.assign(copy.protoyype, SuperClass.prototype);

        /*Re-fixing original constructor*/
        copy.prototype.constructor = Foo;

        return copy;
    }

    baz() { return "This is public!"; }

    _bar() { return "This is private!"; }
}
```

Pero, esta realmente protegido desde afuera de la clase?

Comment: Esto: ***class foo() { ... }*** está mal. En la especificación de ES6, una clase se define así: ***class foo { ... }***. Tienes los paréntesis sobrando en tu definición de la clase `foo`. Igual, comparto la interrogante de @JackNavaRow: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta en concreto?. Saludos

Comment: Si tienes razón esta mal, edito. En cuanto a la pregunta, es si realmente esta protegido afuera del módulo

Comment: Si realmente necesitas encapsulación, creo que te conviene programar en TypeScript. Cualquier solución que intentes con Javascript, te quedará fea. Además, TypeScript compila a Javascript, así que el código generado se puede ejecutar en el navegador.

Answer (score 2):

Hola si podrías encapsular tu programación usando programación modular. Ya que ha la fecha no todos los navegadores soportan ES6.

```
var modulo = (function () {
  var privateMethod = function (message1) {
    console.log(message1);
  };
  var publicMethod = function (mensaje2) {
    privateMethod(mensaje2);
  };
  return {
    publicMethod: publicMethod
  };
})();
/* pasando datos a un método privado */
modulo.publicMethod("mi mensaje");
```

La documentación sobre programación modular [Patron modular en Javascript](https://frontendlabs.io/2643--patron-modular-en-javascript)